# an error occurred trying to load the resource

Tags: cordova, http, ionic-framework

In my ionic project http call throws an error "*an error occurred trying to load the resource*". This issue does not occurs all the time. It returns a status code 0

[image]

Comment: Are you using a caching server perhaps, like Cloudflare?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?